# This map does not have an element with the key in terraform

Tags: terraform

I am doing the following in my `terraform` module:

```
data "vault_policy_document" "this" {

  dynamic "rule" { 
    for_each = {
      for p in var.policy.policy_content : format("%s-%s-%s", p.path, join(",", p.capabilities)) => p
    }

    content {
      path = rule.value.path
      capabilities = rule.value.capabilities
    }
  }
}
```

The variable is declared as

```
variable "policy" {
  description = "The policy to be created"
  type        = map(any)
}
```

and with a certain confidence, it is of the form

```
{
          + "policy-test-1" = {
              + policy_content = [
                  + {
                      + capabilities = [
                          + "read",
                          + "create",
                        ]
                      + path         = "/foo/lala"
                    },
                  + {
                      + capabilities = [
                          + "read",
                          + "create",
                        ]
                      + path         = "/bar/lala"
                    },
                ]
            }
        },
```

Why is the code failing to access the `policy_content` element?

Comment: Looks like your variable has an additional top-level key, `"policy-test-1"`, that you're not accounting for.

Comment: Is there a way to access `policy_content` in my for loop?

Comment: is the intent here to define one policy doc per top-level key ("policy-test-1" and then one rule per item inside "policy_content"? I think a for_each inside the data source itself might be what you're looking for. I will test it out.

Comment: Yes that is the intent; to be able to create a policy with multiple `paths`/`capabilities` pairs; that's why I (am trying to) pass a map whose top level key will be the policy name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial attempt isn't iterating over the keys of the `policy` map, which you can fix by looping the policy document datasource itself over the map:

```
data "vault_policy_document" "this" {
  for_each = var.policy

  dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = {
      for p in each.value.policy_content : format("%s-%s", p.path, join(",", p.capabilities)) => p
    }

    content {
      path         = rule.value.path
      capabilities = rule.value.capabilities
    }
  }
}

resource "vault_policy" "this" {
  for_each = var.policy

  name   = each.key
  policy = data.vault_policy_document.this[each.key].hcl
}
```

This can probably be cleaned up further (like by iterating the policy resource over the data source elements rather than the same policy var again).

But it does produce what looks like the right plan, to me:

```
  # vault_policy.this["policy-test-1"] will be created
  + resource "vault_policy" "this" {
      + id     = (known after apply)
      + name   = "policy-test-1"
      + policy = <<-EOT
            path "/bar/lala" {
              capabilities = ["read", "create"]
            }

            path "/foo/lala" {
              capabilities = ["read", "create"]
            }
        EOT
    }
```